# iOS Location Background Service stops after 10 minutes

Tags: gps, titanium, titanium-mobile, background-service, titanium-alloy

I have a Titanium app that registers an iOS background service, which logs the device's GPS data every 30 seconds. I've registered it as a location service, which is supposed to prevent it from stopping after 10 minutes, however it's not working. Here is the relevant portion of my tiapp.xml:

```
<ios>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>location</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
                <array>
                    <string>gps</string>
                    <string>location-services</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
```

Here is how I register it in alloy.js:

```
if(utils.ios) {
    console.log('registering ios background service');
    Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({ url: 'tracking/backgroundService.js' });
}
```

And the background service itself:

```
var timeout = constants.tracking.interval * 1000;

console.log('starting background gps tracking');

setInterval(function() {
    var user = settings.user();
    if(user && user.password) {
        //user is logged in, let's track them.
        gpsTracking.track();
    }
    else {
        console.log('user is not logged in so not tracking');
    }
}, timeout);
```

This was tested on the iPhone Simulator, I haven't tested on an actual iOS device because the developer site is still down so I can't create a provisioning profile.

I checked my info.plist in the build folder and it's correctly adding the key/array values for UIBackgroundModes and UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities, so I'm not sure what to check next.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer Mr.Chris Bill's answer [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137252/keep-a-background-service-running). I'll describe it for you.

> [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) is a great resource for understanding how the app interacts with the
>   background. There are only a couple different types of apps that are
>   allowed to run in the background (and execute code) for extra time. (I
>   think the normal limit is about 10 minutes).
>
> - Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
> - Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such
>     as a navigation app
> - Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol
>     (VoIP)
> - Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
> - Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
>
> Support for some types of background execution must be declared in advance by
>   the app that uses them. An app declares support for a service using
>   its Info.plist file. Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your Info.plist
>   file and set its value to an array containing one or more of the
>   following strings:
>
> - audio : The app plays audible content to the user
>     while in the background. (This content includes streaming audio or
>     video content using AirPlay.)
> - location : The app keeps users informed of
>     their location, even while it is running in the background.
> - voip : The app provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an
>     Internet connection.
> - newsstand-content : The app is a Newsstand app that
>     downloads and processes magazine or newspaper content in the
>     background.
> - external-accessory—The app works with a hardware accessory
>     that needs to deliver updates on a regular schedule through the
>     External Accessory framework. bluetooth-central—The app works with a
>     Bluetooth accessory that needs to deliver updates on a regular
>     schedule through the CoreBluetooth framework.
>
> So take the info.plist file from your build folder and put it into the root of your project.
>   Then edit it as described above. Hope this helps!

Comment: he clearly stated that he updated the tiapp.xml so there is no need to place the info.plist in the root of the project; In fact that is not the recommended approach any longer

Comment: @Justin: Make sure that you're placing the info.plist file into the root and not into the Resources folder or build folder

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem,seems titanium has a cache logic for GPS location, and can't get the actual latitude and longitude.Also meet the problem like you, 10 minutes it stopped, and if I initial the system iOS map to get the location successfully, back to titanium app, it works again. Very wired.
After a long time investigation and try.

Finally solve the problem by setting the accuracy to ACCURACY_NEAREST_TEN_METERS and using the location event. Now I can get continually GPS updating, the accuracy is also very good, 5 meters.

```
Titanium.Geolocation.setAccuracy(ACCURACY_SET);
Ti.Geolocation.addEventListener('location',evtGpsResult);
```

Hope it can save your problem.